# Can't Play iFrame embedded YouTube video on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I'm developing an iOS iPad app with an embedded YouTube video.

I'm having issues when the user tries to play the video touching the red square play image from YouTube, it seems that pressing that image won't trigger the play action. However, touching anywhere outside the red square play button works.

I've tested it with the iPad user agent with same results.

When embedding with `controls:0` it seems that the action triggers perfectly, but I need the default controls.

Is there anyway to keep `controls:1` and detect that touch to successfully play the video?

Answer (score 2):

Try playing the video itself when it is loaded. If hitting the big red button is not a compulsion add "**event.target.playVideo();**" to the onReady function in the embeded HTML body. I have done so and the player in my application shows the big red button and starts the video itself immediately. I have used the following YouTube iFrame library [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper)